# Convert wordpress site from Salient to Elementor

Tags: wordpress, elementor, wpbakery

I have a Wordpress site made with Salient and WPBakery.

Is it possible to use salient with elementor?

As far as I can tell the theme states that

This theme requires the following plugins: Salient Core and Salient WPBakery Page Builder.

Or do I have to start from scratch?

Answer (score 1):

You can add Elementor and then switch between editors.

Also you can try disabling the built-in editor. I'm not sure about Salient Core, there might be functions for customizing the theme.

If you have pages and posts created in the WPBakery editor, there probably won't be an easy way to convert them to Elementor. You will most likely have to create pages / posts in the new editor from scratch.